# Android - Scaling my UI to fit all screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, scaling

So far I have tried many ways of scaling images to screen sizes and none of them seem to work for me. I am still new to java and the idea of having a UI that fits to any screen size seems foreign to me. I am drawing bitmaps with the Canvas class. I have tried creating a scaledBitmap and have seen no difference. I want a simple main menu screen like this

[image]

This must be a really common issue because all apps would need to do this. I really could use some help understanding how this works. On some phones it looks alright but on others the images are either too large or off centered.

My code is below. If someone could please help me out here, this is for a school project due pretty soon :P Thanks guys!

```
public MainMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);

    titleBounds = new RectF();
    playBounds = new RectF();
    scoreBounds = new RectF();
    soundBounds = new RectF();
    creditBounds = new RectF();

    titlePaint = new Paint();
    playPaint = new Paint();

    play = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play);
    playGlow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.playglow);


    sound = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sound);
    soundGlow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.soundglow);


    // Get window size and save it to screenWidth and screenHeight.
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size); 
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    playy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(play, convertToPx(screenWidth), convertToPx(screenHeight), true);


    playSound(context, R.raw.loop);


}

public int convertToPx(int dp) {
    // Get the screen's density scale
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}


@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)getParent();

    playBounds.set(screenWidth / 2 - play.getWidth() / 2, screenHeight * 1/3 - play.getHeight() / 2, playBounds.left + play.getWidth(), playBounds.top + play.getHeight());
    soundBounds.set(playBounds.centerX() - sound.getWidth() / 2, playBounds.bottom + 10, soundBounds.left + sound.getWidth(), soundBounds.top + sound.getHeight());


    if (playClick == false) canvas.drawBitmap(playy, null, playBounds, null);
    else canvas.drawBitmap(playGlow, null, playBounds, null);   

    if (soundClick == false) canvas.drawBitmap(sound, null, soundBounds, null);
    else canvas.drawBitmap(soundGlow, null, soundBounds, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the image use **scaleType="fitXY"** with this it would span to the bound of the view.

Comment: Im not using XML, so how would I do this

Answer (score 0):

The screen sizes you've gotten from wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize() are in pixels, not in dp. So you can just use them without converting them.

Something like...

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size); 
screenWidth = size.x;
screenHeight = size.y;
playy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(play, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
```

If you are trying to create a game, I would advise against using Canvas. Instead, you should use the faster GLSurfaceView. Better yet, use a cross platform game engine like Corona SDK or Unity or Cocos2dx. Development will be much easier that way, and the performance would be great too.

EDIT: What you ultimately want is a consistent scaling for all your assets without changing their aspect ratio. You need to write an helper method to figure out this ratio, then multiply this ratio to all your dimentions.

```
// The code below assume some variables are already populated by the above code
// I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS CODE. I'M JUST WRITING IT HERE OFF THE TOP OF MY HEAD.

private static float dimRatio;
private static float xOffset;
private static float yOffset;
private static Matrix transformMatrix;

private void initializeBitmapTransformMatrix {
    float ratio = (float)screenWidth / (float)gameWidth; //gameWidth is the width of your background image asset - so it's base size of the game
    if(gameHeight * ratio > screenHeight ){
        // the ratio we calculated above is for the width based scaling.
        // seems like if we use this ratio, the height will go off the boundary.
        // so use the height based ratio instead
        dimRatio = (float)screenHeight / (float)gameHeight;   
        xOffset = (screenWidth - (gameWidth * dimRatio)) / 2;
    } else {
        dimRatio = ratio;
        yOffset = (screenHeight - (gameHeight * dimRatio)) / 2;
    }

    // Now you have the ratio and offset values make a transform matrix

    transformMatrix = new Matrix();
    transformMatrix.setScale(dimRatio, dimRatio);
    transformMatrix.setTranslate(xOffset, yOffset);
}
```

Explanation: We have `dimRatio` to figure out the final pixel value of all your bitmap assets. When you position them, you have to add `xOffset` or `yOffset` accordingly to correctly offset the blank region of the screen, which results from the fact that device screen's aspect ratio is different than your game's intended aspect ratio. The matrix combines all that so we don't have to use these variables every time we draw. We can just use the matrix.

Draw Example:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(play, transformMatrix, null); // for background
// for a button
Matrix buttonMatrix = new Matrix(transformMatrix);
buttonMatrix.postTranslate(20f*dimRatio, 100f*dimRatio);
canvas.drawBitmap(button, buttonMatrix, null);
```

I just wrote this without really testing it. It's just for the idea. Hope you get the idea.

EDIT2: Realized xOffset and yOffset were reversed. Fixed it.

Comment: For the simplicity of the game I am using canvas works great. I have tried what your telling me and it does not work. Would you mind team viewing me?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the problem? I would first try to get the background to take the whole screen by using my code above (just scaling to screen size). Then you can write a method that figure out the ratio of bitmap size vs size you want on the device. You can then just multiply this ratio to all dimensions you would use throughout. One more thing you have to be careful about is that you always have to apply the same ratio to both width and height to retain aspect ratio of your assets. You don't want your circle to be an ellipse.

Comment: Wow. This sounds difficult :'( Like I really dont understand how this works could I take a bit of your time to team view? I dont understand the ratios

Comment: It's not that difficult. I'll try to write it in my answer.

Comment: Okay, could you please? Ive been trying to figure this out for a really long time

Comment: So your saying the gameHeight is the background? The background is scaled to the size of the screen. What is that gameHeight for?

Comment: gameHeight and gameWidth are the intended dimension of your game. Typically your static background image asset should have this exact dimension. Right?

Comment: I also found out that if you are using Rect instead of Matrix, you don't have to pre-scale bitmap. Canvas scales it to fit to that Rect. I think this might be what you want... If you are going to use Matrix like my answer, you need to create a copy of that `transformMatrix` and add more translates to define the placement. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I can just set the size of my Rect's to that ratio then?

Comment: Yes. So instead of applying the scaling in the bitmap, applying in the Rect object. I would do it the matrix way though so you don't have to keep adding offsets to your Rect and multiply the ratio. You just make a copy of that transform matrix and use it without thinking about offset/ratio stuff.

Comment: Do you have teamview? Im sure its really easy but its gonna take a lot longer to explain over stack overflow :S