# How do i get the screen scaling value on windows in java

Tags: java, windows

I have a 4k display on my laptop, therefore I use windows scaling 200%.
Is there a way to get the scaling value of the os in java, so that i can size my graphics appropriately?

Comment: Take a look at this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190832/android-scaling-my-ui-to-fit-all-screen-sizes

Comment: @NickMeyer that's for android...  Elias did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CamHart No, I did not find any solution that i pursued, but a quick google now yielded some promising result. You can get the value in c#, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586883/windows-scaling, and using this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java you could probably access it in Java. Unfortunately i do not have a windows machine to test this on, but be sure to let me know how it went if you choose to pursue it :)